# Finding intersections between two sine waves of different frequency, phase, amplitude, and offset

Tags: trigonometry

How would you go about finding -- or even approximating -- values of $\theta$ that would satisfy an equation like the one below? It's been a long time since my last trig class and I can't think of any identities that would be useful for solving in terms of $\theta$ here.

$$\sin(\theta)=a\sin(b\theta+c)+d$$

Ideally I'd like a way to find all the intersections, if any, over a specific period (say $0<=\theta<=1$). If that can't be done directly and there's a way to find just the first intersection where $\theta>=0$, that would be great (and I suspect the same method could be repeated to find the next intersection after that, and so on).

If there's a vastly simpler way to just figure out *whether* there's at least one intersection within a given range of values of $\theta$, then I'd be interested in that too -- but I'd really like to be able to find exact $\theta$ values.

I know that there will be no intersections at all if:

- $|d|>|a-1|$, or
- $a=b=1$, $d\ne0$, and $c$ is a multiple of $2\pi$

-- but I don't think that's useful for figuring out whether/where there are intersections if neither of those conditions apply.

Background, if it matters: I'd be using this in a computer program to generate musical rhythms based on interactions between two rotating polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Unless frequencies have an integer ratio, numerical iterative solution is the only way. The solutions are seen as intersection in a graph of the two sine function curves.